# this.$.element error in dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I have the a polymer element with this piece of template:
[image: structure]
Element: `<my-tiendas>`

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tiendas}}" as="tienda">
    <my-tiendaitem tienda="{{tienda}}"></my-tiendaitem>
</template>
```

The element `my-tiendaitem` is another polymer element that has the features to show the list item:

```
<div class="card-container">
            <div class="back" id="back">
                <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:mode-edit" id="updBt" class="edit-class"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:delete" id="delBt" class="delete-class"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:more-vert" id="moreBt" class="more-class"></paper-icon-button>
            </div>
            <div class="front" id="front">
                <iron-icon icon="my-icons:store" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
                <div class="content" id="content">
                    <span class="nombre">{{tienda.tiendaNombre}}</span>
                    <span class="direccion">{{tienda.tiendaAddress}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In `my-tiendaitem` I have a functionality that allow me to swipe to the left and show action buttons, to do this i need some event listeners like:

```
 ready() {
            super.ready();

            this._front = this.$.front;
            this._back = this.$.back;

            this._updBt = this.$.updBt;
            this._delBt = this.$.delBt;
            this._moreBt = this.$.moreBt;

            this.onStart = this.onStart.bind(this);
            this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);
            this.onEnd = this.onEnd.bind(this);
            this.update = this.update.bind(this);

            this.updClick = this.updClick.bind(this);
            this.delClick = this.delClick.bind(this);
            this.moreClick = this.moreClick.bind(this);
            this.updateBecauseOfClick = this.updateBecauseOfClick.bind(this);

            this.target = null;

            this.startX = 0;
            this.currentX = 0;
            this.dragginCard = false;
            this.screenX = 0;
            this.causeClick = false;
            this.addEventListener();

            requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
        }

        addEventListener(){
            this._front.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onStart);
            this._front.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onMove);
            this._front.addEventListener('touchend', this.onEnd);

            this._updBt.addEventListener('click', this.updClick);
            this._delBt.addEventListener('click', this.delClick);
            this._moreBt.addEventListener('click', this.moreClick);
        }
```

I'm getting always an error in the console:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

And that it is because `this.$.front` is undefined. There is anyway to solve this issue? I'm using Polymer 2 the last release.

Comment: This implies that the element is not static. Is the associated element inside a `dom-if` or `dom-repeat` within `my-tiendaitem`?

Comment: @tony19, you are correct `my-tiendaitem` is a child element that will be created dynamically inside the dom-repeat, but I 'm not trying to access dynamically dom objects because the error is inside the child element that has its own dom

Comment: @Dracco I'm not accessing outside dom elements, it is accessing dom elements inside the child element from the child element not from the parent, check on the image that i shared

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I posted an answer below. The confusion was brought by your code as you provided the template outside of your component, which makes absolutely no difference to what's happening inside of it. It also happened to be `dom-repeat`, while 99% of questions about `this.$.***` being undefined is about accessing dynamic content.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera Can you update the question to show the template of `my-tiendaitem`? It would be helpful to see how "front" is defined and how `addEventListener` is related. A repro in jsbin/codepen, etc. would be helpful.

Comment: @tony19 the template of `my-tiendaitem` it is the second pice of code in the question

Comment: Ok, is that the entire template for `my-tiendaitem`?

Comment: @tony19, yes it is the complete template

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NYmGjP?editors=1010)

Comment: @tony19 for me it works okay but try to put your own custom element inside a dom-repeat? That is where the issue comes up

Comment: @tony19 I did the same test than you and it works perfectly fine outside the dom-repeat. The problem is to put into a dom-repeat

Comment: Put what exactly into a dom-repeat? Can you show me with a codepen?

Comment: you already did in codepen one custom element, please could you create a parent custom element with a dom-repeat and inside the dom-repeat show the custom element that you have already created? I cant do it because i don't work before with codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to your custom `addEventListener` method masking the element's [native `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which Polymer is trying to call in setting up `dom-repeat` children. You'll have to rename your `addEventListener` method (e.g., to `_addEventListener`).

```
class Foo extends Polymer.Element {
  // addEventListener() { // DON'T NAME IT THIS
  _addEventListener() {
    ...
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NYmGjP?editors=1010)

Comment: perfect, that was the problem, thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element's use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()` or it's shorthand `this.$$(selector)`
You can read more about it in the Polymer documentation in the section [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom)

Comment: thanks for your support, but I'm not trying to find dynamically nodes inside a dom-repeat, what i'm doing is reference DOM objects in the shadow dom in the child element, if you see there is two elements, the child element should be manage it self that's why I'm using this.$.domelement